# Apple's cut of ecommerce application

Tags: app-store, e-commerce

We are wanting to modify our app and create a way to allow mobile users to shop at our store. I know apple get's 30% of the revenue from the App sales itself, but do they get 30% of the sales made through our app? If so, Would we be better off making an ecommerce website designed for mobile users and then making a link to that page from our app? If we do that, would Apple still get a portion of our revenue? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, same 70/30 finding a link now...

http://www.businessinsider.com/apple-lets-iphone-app-developers-sell-stuff-in-free-apps-2009-10

Now this is just using apple's in-app APIs. If you just have people buy stuff through your store from the app but bypassing Apple they get no cut.

EDIT::

Actually here is a better answer:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/60030-will-apple-take-commission-app-sells-goods-within-app.html

> Yeah, they're not keen on you selling things out with their store because yes, they do want your 30%. I think newspapers and magazines are currently battling with them over some sort of subscription that works similar to this but for now you're unlikely to get this through the net.

.

> Amazon and a few others get around this by having a buy button that launches their website in Mobile Safari, where you can sell items without any Apple involvement.

Comment: That's what I was wondering about. I know a lot of ecommerce sites have their own apps (i.e. amazon and ebay) but I didn't know if they were actual apps for shoping, or if they simply launched the browser. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Apple takes 30% of the price of the app in the store, not the revenue generated through it. How could they keep track of this revenue?